# Get Payment Update for orders with Pending Payment Review status

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

Magento 1.9.X

Need a code to do the following: Run function "Get Payment Update" for each order that has status "Pending Payment Review" if order on authorize.net is approved, save order and update order status to Processing.

I could then set up the cron to run above function every hour or so.

**Here is the code I have right now, but I had this code running for just changing all Order statuses to Processing, which is not convenient:**

```
   <?php
     include_once './app/Mage.php';
     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

     $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('pending_payment','payment_review')));

     foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        $fullOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $fullOrder->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
        $fullOrder->setStatus('processing', false);
        $fullOrder->save();

        try {
          if(!$fullOrder->canInvoice()) {
             Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
          }
          $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $fullOrder)->prepareInvoice();
          if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
             Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
          }
          $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
          $invoice->register();
          $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
          $transactionSave->save();
        } 
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        }
     }

  ?>
```

Thanks in advance!